# Is semi-direct product represent all group (up to isom) of order 6?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

We have $|G|=6$ and by sylow thm we have $n_{3}=1\ n_{2}=1\ or\ 3$ this implies $\exists H \in Syl_{3}(G)$ and $H\lhd G$. Let $K \in Syl_{2}(G)$, then $H\cap K = {1}$ and $HK=G$ and $G\cong K\times_{\tau}H$ for some $\tau:K\rightarrow Aut(H)$

(1)My first question is why $HK=G$?

(2)Why $G\cong K\times_{\tau}H$ for some $\tau:K\rightarrow Aut(H)$?

Comment: (1): This is just by counting. (2) this follows from (1).

Comment: The answer to first one is that let $K={1,x}$ and  $H={1,y,y^2}$, and $$xy\neq x\ or\ y\ since y\neq 1,\ xy\neq 1\ or\ y^2 since\ y\neq x\ xy\notin H\ and\ K$$ and, similarly $xy^2\notin H\ and\ K$. Thus, we find all distict elemts.

Comment: It could perhaps be a good idea to choose a nick that can be typed by most people here, not to mention pronounced...

Comment: Thx, @DonAntonio , good advice!

Answer (score 0):

Let $H=\{1,y,y^2\}$ and $K=\{1,x\}$. And, follow the replies above. $G=\{1,y,y^2,x,xy,xy^2\}$. We know $H\lhd G$ and $K\leq G$
$$\forall g_1,g_2\in G\ g_1=h_1k_1\ g_2=h_2k_2,\ h_1,h_2\in H\ and\ k_1,k_2\in K$$
Observe that:
$$g_1g_2=(h_1k_1)(h_2k_2)=h_1k_1h_2(k_1^{-1}k_1)k_2=h_1(k_1h_2k_1^{-1})k_1k_2$$
Let $h_3=xyx^{-1}\in H$, so $h_3=1\ or\ y\ or\ y^2$

Case1:
$$If\ h_3=1\Rightarrow y=1 \ contradiction$$

Case2:
$$If\ h_3=y\Rightarrow y=y$$
then let $\tau:K\rightarrow Aut(H)\ \tau(1)=id_H\ and\ \tau(x)=id_H\ and\ \tau\ is\ homomorphism.$ $G\cong K\times_\tau H$

Case3:
$$If\ h_3=y\Rightarrow h_2=y^2$$
then let $\tau:K\rightarrow Aut(H)\ \tau(1)=id_H\ and\ \tau(x):\{1,y,y^2\}\rightarrow \{1,y^2,y\},\ respectively.\ \tau\ is\ homomorphism.$ $G\cong K\times_\tau H$